# findHomography, getPerspectiveTransform, & getAffineTransform

Tags: c++, opencv, affinetransform, homography

This question is on the OpenCV functions `findHomography`, `getPerspectiveTransform` & `getAffineTransform`

1. What is the difference between `findHomography` and `getPerspectiveTransform`?. My understanding from the documentation is that `getPerspectiveTransform` computes the transform using 4 correspondences (which is the minimum required to compute a homography/perspective transform) where as `findHomography` computes the transform even if you provide more than 4 correspondencies (presumably using something like a least squares method?).
   Is this correct?
   (In which case the only reason OpenCV still continues to support getPerspectiveTransform should be legacy? )
2. My next concern is that I want to know if there is an equivalent to `findHomography` for computing an Affine transformation? i.e. a function which uses a least squares or an equivalent robust method to compute and affine transformation.
   According to the documentation `getAffineTransform` takes in only 3 correspondences (which is the min required to compute an affine transform).

Best,

Comment: Maybe [estimateRigidTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform) would fit your needs.

Answer (score 45):

**Q #1**: Right, the findHomography tries to find the best transform between two sets of points. It uses something smarter than least squares, called RANSAC, which has the ability to reject outliers - if at least 50% + 1 of your data points are OK, RANSAC will do its best to find them, and build a reliable transform.

The getPerspectiveTransform has a lot of useful reasons to stay - it is the base for findHomography, and it is useful in many situations where you only have 4 points, and you know they are the correct ones. The findHomography is usually used with sets of points detected automatically - you can find many of them, but with low confidence. getPerspectiveTransform is good when you kn ow for sure 4 corners - like manual marking, or automatic detection of a rectangle.

**Q #2** There is no equivalent for affine transforms. You can use findHomography, because affine transforms are a subset of homographies.

Comment: the response Q#2 isn't true as of opencv 4.X: there're estimateAffine2D and estimateAffine3D which are the equivalent of findHomography for affine transforms

Answer (score 14):

I concur with everything @vasile has written. I just want to add some observations:

`getPerspectiveTransform()` and `getAffineTransform()` are meant to work on *4* or *3* points (respectively), that are *known to be correct correspondences*. On real-life images taken with a real camera, you can **never** get correspondences that accurate, not with automatic nor manual marking of the corresponding points.

There are always outliers. *Just look at the simple case* of wanting to fit a curve through points (e.g. take a generative equation with noise `y1 = f(x) = 3.12x + gauss_noise` or `y2 = g(x) = 0.1x^2 + 3.1x + gauss_noise`): it will be much more easier to find a good quadratic function to estimate the points in both cases, than a good linear one. Quadratic might be an overkill, but in most cases will not be (after removing outliers), and if you want to fit a straight line there you better be mightily sure that is the right model, otherwise you are going to get unusable results.

That said, if you *are mightily sure* that affine transform is the right one, here's a suggestion:

- use `findHomography`, that has *RANSAC* incorporated in to the functionality, to get rid of the outliers and get an initial estimate of the image transformation
- select 3 correct matches-correspondances (that fit with the homography found), or reproject 3 points from the 1st image to the 2nd (using the homography)
- use those 3 matches (that are as close to correct as you can get) in `getAffineTransform()`
- wrap all of that in your own `findAffine()` if you want - and voila!

Comment: Is there a way to to find the best "Affine" matrix? I want to force the last row of the homography to be [0, 0, 1].

Comment: @Drazick The "algorithm" I have written does almost that -- it uses findHomography to get rid of outliers and so that you don't have to code your own RANSAC, and than you can use getAffineTransform() on any 3 points to get a close-to-best affine. Alternatevley, you could code your own RANSAC algorithm with getAffineTransform() instead of getPerspectiveTransform() as a core function.

Comment: @penleope, I found a solution how to find the best (l2 wise) affine transform using SVD in a manner similar to the way you estimate the best homography.

Comment: @Drazick great. Describe it in an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Re Q#2, estimateRigidTransform is the oversampled equivalent of getAffineTransform. I don't know if it was in OCV when this was first posted, but it's available in 2.4.

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy solution for the finding the Affine transform for the system of over-determined equations.

1. Note that in general an Affine transform finds a solution to the over-determined system of linear equations Ax=B by using a pseudo-inverse or a similar technique, so

**x = (A A<sup>t</sup> )<sup>-1</sup>  A<sup>t</sup>  B**

Moreover, this is handled in the core openCV functionality by a simple call to solve(A, B, X).

2. Familiarize yourself with the code of Affine transform in opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp: it really does just two things:

   a. rearranges inputs to create a system Ax=B;

   b. then calls solve(A, B, X);

NOTE: ignore the function comments in the openCV code - they are confusing and don’t reflect the actual ordering of the elements in the matrices. If you are solving [u, v]’= Affine * [x, y, 1] the rearrangement is:

```
         x1 y1 1 0  0  1
         0  0  0 x1 y1 1
         x2 y2 1 0  0  1
    A =  0  0  0 x2 y2 1
         x3 y3 1 0  0  1
         0  0  0 x3 y3 1

    X = [Affine11, Affine12, Affine13, Affine21, Affine22, Affine23]’

         u1 v1
    B =  u2 v2
         u3 v3
```

All you need to do is to add more points. To make Solve(A, B, X) work on over-determined system add DECOMP_SVD parameter. To see the powerpoint slides on the topic, use this [link](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/s.prince/book/15_Models_For_Transformations.pptx). If you’d like to learn more about the pseudo-inverse in the context of computer vision, the best source is: [ComputerVision](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/s.prince/book/book.pdf), see chapter 15 and appendix C.

If you are still unsure how to add more points see my code below:

```
// extension for n points;
cv::Mat getAffineTransformOverdetermined( const Point2f src[], const Point2f dst[], int n )
{
    Mat M(2, 3, CV_64F), X(6, 1, CV_64F, M.data); // output
    double* a = (double*)malloc(12*n*sizeof(double));
    double* b = (double*)malloc(2*n*sizeof(double));
    Mat A(2*n, 6, CV_64F, a), B(2*n, 1, CV_64F, b); // input

    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        int j = i*12;   // 2 equations (in x, y) with 6 members: skip 12 elements
        int k = i*12+6; // second equation: skip extra 6 elements
        a[j] = a[k+3] = src[i].x;
        a[j+1] = a[k+4] = src[i].y;
        a[j+2] = a[k+5] = 1;
        a[j+3] = a[j+4] = a[j+5] = 0;
        a[k] = a[k+1] = a[k+2] = 0;
        b[i*2] = dst[i].x;
        b[i*2+1] = dst[i].y;
    }

    solve( A, B, X, DECOMP_SVD );
    delete a;
    delete b;
    return M;
}

// call original transform
vector<Point2f> src(3);
vector<Point2f> dst(3);
src[0] = Point2f(0.0, 0.0);src[1] = Point2f(1.0, 0.0);src[2] = Point2f(0.0, 1.0);
dst[0] = Point2f(0.0, 0.0);dst[1] = Point2f(1.0, 0.0);dst[2] = Point2f(0.0, 1.0);
Mat M = getAffineTransform(Mat(src), Mat(dst));
cout<<M<<endl;
// call new transform
src.resize(4); src[3] = Point2f(22, 2);
dst.resize(4); dst[3] = Point2f(22, 2);
Mat M2 = getAffineTransformOverdetermined(src.data(), dst.data(), src.size());
cout<<M2<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

getAffineTransform:affine transform is combination of translation, scale, shear, and rotation
https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/affine-transformation.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/2d_transformation.htm

getPerspectiveTransform：perspective transform is project mapping
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/268uP.png)