# What's the difference between getAffineTransform(), getPerspectiveTransform() and findHomography()

Tags: python, opencv

I'm investigating ways of transforming an image and overlaying it within a contour of another image.

As best as I can tell there are three ways to do this with OpenCV in Python:

1. `getAffineTransform()`
2. `getPerspectiveTransform()`
3. `findHomography()`

I found three different methods via blog and SO posts and they all produce the same results, i.e. taking a source image and warping/overlaying on a contour of a different shape on a destination image.

This demonstrates `getAffineTransform()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/38323528/1887261

This demonstrates `getPerspectiveTransform()`  http://uberhip.com/python/image-processing/opencv/2014/10/26/warping-brien/

This demonstrates `findHomography()` http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/#download

I'm wondering what is the best method to use and why would you use one over the other?

Comment: Please use a better title -- there should be something after "between"

Comment: accident, fixing!

Comment: read the doc to find hints about differences. For example findHomography allows you to choose different robust methods (for example RANSAC) which is nice if you expect a lot of outliers in the point correspondences.

Comment: There is difference between Homography and affine transform itself

Comment: getAffineTransform uses 3 point pairs, so it is not a "perspective homography" but only has 6 dof. This will make a transformation more stable and less error prone, but can't handle perspective effects, so the transformation will typically not give perfect results.

Comment: getPerspectiveTransform and getAffineTransform use the minimum number of necessary point pairs to compute the transformation (4 and 3), which perfectly maps the points. findHomography (and estimateRigidTransform) use/allow more point pairs to optimize a result.

Comment: Duplicate of this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237948/findhomography-getperspectivetransform-getaffinetransform

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.findHomography` finds the perspective transformation between two frames. `cv2.warpPerspective` takes that image transformation between two frames and applies it to the image.
Below is some code I wrote for homework the other day:

```
H, masked = cv.findHomography(src, dst, cv.RANSAC, 5.0)

dst = cv.warpPerspective(topright,H,(topleft.shape[1] + topright.shape[1], topleft.shape[0])
```