# how to map a point from one polygon to another?

Tags: image, opencv, homography

I have a picture of a football field as follows:
[Football Field Side View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/api4v.jpg)

I have another picture of a football field from a topdown view as follows:
[Football Field Top View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJss8.jpg)

My question is how to map a point on the former to the latter.
We have tried the following method where **side_view_points** and **top_view_points** are the corresponding points of the images we are trying to match:

> cv2.findHomography(side_view_corners, top_view_corners)

However we are not getting accurate results.
We have used 12 points to find the homography matrix. Still getting completely incorrect results.

Is there any other method or something we are missing to get more accurate results?

Comment: `cv2.findHomography` doesn't work well with warped images.
I think you should use warping rather than `cv2.findHomography`.

Comment: @SuhyeonLee By warping do you mean warpPerspective?
Because acc to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237948/findhomography-getperspectivetransform-getaffinetransform
cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() is a subset of cv2.findHomography()